# Custom xml attributes without attrs.xml file

Tags: android, xml, layout, view

Recently I've faced with adding custom xml parameters to my views in xml layout. I know that I should use attrs.xml file for this purpose, but... I have found, that I can use custom parameters without any attrs.xml file at all. Can somebody explain this ? Is this a bug or is this a valid case ?

here is my custom view:

```
public class TestView extends View {

public TestView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public TestView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    final String scheme = "http://red.com/ui/scheme";
    if (attrs != null) {
        Log.d("TestView", "custom param value: " + attrs.getAttributeValue(scheme, "cutom"));
    }
}
```

}

and here is the main layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:red="http://red.com/ui/scheme"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello" />

<com.red.ui.TestView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffAABBCC"
    red:cutom="customvalue"
    />

 </LinearLayout>
```

It is a simple scratch project, created by Android wizard.

Comment: I was looking for something like this as I found it a bit annoying that I needed to have "attrs.xml". It seems to make it more complicated to share custom views between projects. However, your above solution didn't work for me: when I removed my custom attribute from attrs.xml, the layout xml would not compile... it says "No resource identifier for attribute 'x' in package 'y'", indicating that the attribute must be declared in attrs.xml or the parser won't recognise it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The custom attribute that you added is not available in R.java
I think the main motto of making custom attributes is to use it at multiple places. 
But through this code we cann't accomplish the same scenario.

Here is the sample code - attrs.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
 <declare-styleable name="MyLayout">
    <attr name="text" format="string" />
 </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

I am changing main.xml to add the the text attribute

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:red="http://red.com/ui/scheme"
  xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.psl"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello"
    myapp:text="Text String" />

<com.psl.TestView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffAABBCC"
    myapp:text="My Special Text String"
    red:cutom="customvalue" />

</LinearLayout>
```

TestView.java -

```
public class TestView extends View {

public TestView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
this(context, attrs, 0);
}

public TestView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyle) {
super(context, attrs, defStyle);
final String scheme = "http://red.com/ui/scheme";
if (attrs != null) {
    Log.d("TestView", "custom param value: " + attrs.getAttributeValue(scheme, "cutom"));
}

TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
        R.styleable.MyLayout);
CharSequence s = a.getString(R.styleable.MyLayout_text);
Log.d("MyTestView", "attrs param value: " + s.toString());
}
}
```

If you noticed after making the attr in attrs.xml. It is available everywhere. 
But the attr defined in xml itself through custom namespace is available only through the namespace that you have to define everywhere.
May be its a bug because the attribute is getting added to some custom namespace and not in the application itself.

Comment: hi, try not posting questions as answers.

Comment: Goal: read my custom xml attributes from within my custom view (for example to make it configurable via xml layout only). But according to any tutorials I've read: https://staticallytyped.wordpress.com/2011/04/16/android-custom-xml-attributes-and-views/, http://kevindion.com/2011/01/custom-xml-attributes-for-android-widgets/ and so on, to accomplish that goal I have to declare my custom attributes in attrs.xml file. But, I found that it is not neccesary. And I showed this possibility hereinbefore. So the question is whether this usage(without atts file) is allowed ? Or it is some kind of hack?

Comment: Is this answer helpful ? Or have you any other issue

Comment: Yeah, I think it was helpful... But, it turned out, that the only difference is a kind of "convenience" in accessing attributes using R class ? I don't see any issue with declaring namespaces each time I want to use custom params inside the view. Or, its all about  specifying a set of supported attributes and their types so anyone knows what type he should look for in attributes using styled access? The sharp difference (and the key point why it is much more easier and conveniently) in using styled access is quite blurry for me for now.

Comment: It's convenient may be to call it for once. But if you have to specify the namespace in your code 100 times.Then it gets clumsy. You should have a practice to add it in attrs.xml. Then the attr gets added to your application itself.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. Things got a bit clearer. PS. namespace would be helpful in case if you can not declare your own attrs file (like distributing your View subclasses in jars to 3-rd party developers)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a "bug" of course. This is how you use a custom view in your xml.
refer to this : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html

Comment: Tho one thing I found related is: "The other attributes and parameters in the definition are the ones passed into the custom component constructor, and then passed through to the EditText constructor, so they are the same parameters that you would use for an EditText view. Note that it is possible to add your own parameters as well, and we will touch on this again below.". But this is almost last sentence... It didn't help much.